# How to create a generic key-value store in Apache ignite, query using SQL and delete the store using Spring Boot and Spring Data

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, ignite, protobuf-java

I'm new to Apache Ignite and I'm feeling a bit confused about how to implement what I need.

I have a Spring Boot project with the Ignite depedencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
  <artifactId>ignite-spring-data_2.2</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
  <artifactId>ignite-spring-boot-autoconfigure-ext</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
  <artifactId>ignite-spring-boot-thin-client-autoconfigure-ext</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

These are the versions set in the POM:

```
<ignite.version>2.13.0</ignite.version>
<h2.version>1.4.197</h2.version>
```

What I need to do is creating a generic key-value store (<String, ProtobufObject>), add some elements and query these elements using SQL (doing some sorting, paging etc.) and delete the store.

If I autowire

```
@Autowired
private Ignite ignite;
```

I don't get much to work with. Implementing a CrudRepository is out-of-place since it doesn't create or destroy stores/tables.But maybe it's just that I'm feeling confused. How can I easily and flexibly implement the above using the Java Ignite API?

Any hint is welcome and appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tutorial: https://www.gridgain.com/docs/tutorials/spring/spring-ignite-tutorial

and this reference: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/extensions-and-integrations/spring/spring-boot

Comment: Hello, thanks for the example! Some notes: that example shows how to execute an SQL using @Query but it doesn't explain how to create a *generic* key-value store (<String, ProtobufObject>) (a.k.a NoSQL database) and delete the store using the Java client.